# Checking UITableViewAutomaticDimension returns -1

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my code I want to make a decision if to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` or `UITableViewAutomaticDimension + constant` for example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  if UITableViewAutomaticDimension <= someConst {
    return someConst
  }
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

However it seems that each time I check UITableViewAutomaticDimension it's -1 however if I directly return the value the height comes out correct. Is it not possible to peek into UITableViewAutomaticDimension this way? I want to check the height the cell would be if UITableViewAutomaticDimension and then make a decision on what the cell height return should be. Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is wrong. `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` works only with Autolayout. Also, it does not return the height of the row by calculating it and will always return -1. It simply tells that the tableview height should be calculated based on the constraints of the cell.

Check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) tutorial to learn more about self-sizing cells.